# How to get camera rotation in libGDX?

Tags: camera, libgdx, rotation

I want to get the rotation of the OrthograpicCamera in libGDX.
I'm currently using this formula that I copied from another SOF post:

```
float camRotation = -(float)Math.atan2(cam.up.x, cam.up.y)*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
```

This returns -0.0 if I don't rotate.

If I rotate by 1 `cam.rotate(1f);` it camRotation prints -1.0
& if I rotate by -1 `cam.rotate(-1f);` camRotation prints 1.0

I'm confused by the math. What's the proper way to get camera rotation in libGDX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it only the minus sign at the beginning of

```
-(float)Math.atan2(cam.up.x, cam.up.y)*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
```

that is causing your confusion, if you remove that it should work as you expect.

`atan2(b, a)` gives you the angle between the positive x-axis and the point `(a, b)`. Note calling it for `(b, a)` give the angle to the point `(a, b)` and not to point `(b, a)`

In the example code you have `atan2` is called with arguments `cam.up.y` and `cam.up.x` where `cam.up` is a unit-vector which indicates what is up.

So in an unrotated camera the up-vector would be `(0, 1)` (it's actually a 3-dimensional vector but we can ignore the z-axis for now), if we plug that into the definition of `atan2` is says that we should get the angle between positive-x `(1, 0)` and up (but with the arguments flipped) `(1, 0)`, which is zero.

So using `atan2` to compare the up vector to the positive x-axis is a valid way of finding the rotation of the camera.